# Saving html file by POST only works once

Tags: php, post

I have a html page (database.html) that contains a table you can edit via javascript. The following PHP script is used for saving the the page.

The PHP script saves the updated version of database.html and redirects to the new version (same file).

The problem is that it doesn't work the second time you press save, only the first time.

Any ideas what the problem can be?

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><head>
<title>Database</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
#textarea_database {
display:none;
}
</style>
<script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a id="a_save" href="#">Save</a>

<form id="form_database" method="post" action="save.php">
<textarea id="textarea_database" name="textarea_database"></textarea>
</form>

<div id="contenteditable" contenteditable="true">
Write something and press save...
</div>

</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
window.onload = function () {

    var a_save = document.getElementById('a_save'),
        form_database = document.getElementById('form_database'),
        textarea_database = document.getElementById('textarea_database');

    a_save.onclick = function () {
        textarea_database.value = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
        form_database.submit();
    }
}
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

// the textarea contain all th html
$textarea_database =  $_POST["textarea_database"];

// add doctype since javascript document.documentElement.innerHTML dont get it
$textarea_database = '<!DOCTYPE html>' . $textarea_database;

// update the html database file
$open_database = fopen('database.html','w+');
fputs($open_database,$textarea_database);
fclose($open_database);


// redirect to the uppdated database (timestamp prevent browser cache)
$the_time = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s');
$url_and_time = "database.html?" . $the_time;
header("Location: $url_and_time ");
exit;

?>
```

Comment: what happens the second time?

Comment: You will probably have to include your html and javascript here as well

Comment: So the user can type in HTML, that HTML is stored in a file on the server, in fact the same file you are currently using, and then you reload the page to show the changes etc. Sounds both strange and risky (very risky), and hopefully it's just a fun exercise and not something you intend to use on an actual website!

Comment: Thanks for comments. Now I discovered that the problem only occurs in chrome and safari. It only works to update every second time.

Comment: Adeneo, It's not for a public website. But thanks for the warning :)

Comment: @user1087110: how long are you waiting before each test?  Are you clicking "submit", and then as soon as the page loads clicking "submit" again?

Comment: Justin Gingy McDonald, second time I get back the html from first save.

Comment: @user1087110: how long are you waiting between each time you click "submit"?!  And what is the server like?

Comment: cegfault: I can wait for a minute. Still only work's every secound time in safari and chrome.